# Check for null in my LINQ query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Afternoon,
I cant seem to work out how to ignore if the following line is null

```
where ((double)t.twePrice >= priceFrom && (double)t.twePrice <= (priceTo))
```

As you can see in my code below i am able to do this when its a string. But I am having issues with the prices one. Could someone please shed some light for me?

```
from a in dc.aboProducts
join t in dc.tweProducts on a.sku equals t.sku
where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productSku) || productSku == t.sku)
where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productAsin) || productAsin == a.asin)
where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productName) || t.title.Contains(productName))
where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productBrand) || t.brand.Contains(productBrand))
where ((double)t.twePrice >= priceFrom && (double)t.twePrice <= (priceTo))
select new GetProducts
```

**UPDATE:** I am basically sending over a load of items to search my MS SQL Database, Some of these may be NULL as per the strings. The prices may also be null as are not needed all the time. So if the prices are null, i dont need to use them.

Many thanks.

Comment: do you mean to say that "priceFrom" and "priceTo" can be null, and in that case you want to ignore this query?

Comment: Yeah they can be null and need to be ignored if they are as with the other options :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following might be enough:

```
where ((priceFrom == null || (double)t.twePrice >= priceFrom) && (priceTo == null || (double)t.twePrice <= priceTo))
```

For readability it might break in two:

```
where (priceFrom == null || (double)t.twePrice >= priceFrom) 
where (priceTo == null || (double)t.twePrice <= priceTo)
```

Comment: thanks but this does not work, I have updated my question as i just noticed i missed off some vital details!

Comment: Does the second of my statements not cover it?

Comment: no :( the tweprice will never be null. only priceFrom and priceTo may be as they are being passed in to the query

Answer (score 0):

Check that twePrice is not null for example:

```
where (t.twePrice != null && (double)t.twePrice >= priceFrom && (double)t.twePrice <= (priceTo))
```

@thatuxguy, I guess you need some thing like this. below code ignore the condition in case of twePrice being null.

```
where (t.twePrice == null ? true : (double)t.twePrice >= priceFrom && (double)t.twePrice <= (priceTo))
```

Good Luck !!